# Drawing a color map in matlab

Tags: matlab, colormap

I have a data file with 4 columns. First 3 columns represent the x y and z coordinates, and the 4th column indicates the intensity of that point (x,y,z). I need to plot this in 3d and shows its intensity through color. I guess it is called color map. How can I do it.

Comment: MATLAB is very precise about thise things. It it is points, use `scatter3`. If you want to have a surface use `surf` and if you want to plot a bar, which indicates that the colors indicate, you need to look for `colorbar`.

Comment: But I have a fourth column which I need to represent in terms of color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about [`scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#d120e1108473)?
The iputs `x`, `y`, `z` are the coordinates `s` is the circle size and `c` is the color.
You can use fix size and play with the color to represent the intensity of the data

Comment: But I have a fourth column which I need to represent in terms of color.

Comment: the C in  scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C) is a vector of color markers specified as a an RGB triplets. you can specify the color. you should transform your 4th column to represent RGB triplets.
I recommend you to first visualized how you want the plot to look like than try to make it happened.
when you'll have a code we will be able to help more with it

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this previously, I will try and get back if I have any trouble. Thanks